# select most recent records with unique user id

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a database table that contains multiple entries for each user during a period of time. The query I'm trying to build will only return the most recent record for each user during that time period.

what I have thus far:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM picks_recorded)
WHERE date_submitted > '" . $week_start . "'
AND date_submitted < '" . $week_end . "'
ORDER BY date_submitted DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I've tried several versions of this without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct p.* from 
picks_recorded p
inner join
(select userid, max(date_submitted) as maxdate from picks_recorded
WHERE date_submitted > '" . $week_start . "'
AND date_submitted < '" . $week_end . "'
group by userid) s on p.userid = s.userid and p.date_submitted = s.maxdate
```

Basically, we use group by to get the maximum value of `date_submitted` per `userid` i.e. date of latest record for each user. Then we inner join with the source table based on the `userid` and `submitted_date` to get all the required data.

Note: Using `distinct` in the outer query will ensure that only one row is returned for a given user if that user has multiple, identical records for the latest date. However, if you have 2 records with same `userid` and `submitted_date`, but even one different field, then both records will be returned. In that case, you need to provide additional logic to say which of the 2 records should be kept in the final result.

On a side note, you should avoid building queries by concatenating with variables. Instead, you should use prepared statements/parameterised queries.

Comment: If there are multiple records for the same date_submitted for the same user, there can be multiple rows per user in the final result.

Comment: Yes, agreed. But we would then need more info from OP about deciding which of those n possible rows should be kept.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `DISTINCT *` into this `DISTINCT(userid)`.
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(userid) FROM picks_recorded)
WHERE
    date_submitted > '" . $week_start . "'
    AND
    date_submitted < '" . $week_end . "'
ORDER BY date_submitted DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the most recent row by user during a certain period by using `not exists`. i.e. select only those rows during a period where a more recent row for that user does not exist

```
SELECT *
FROM picks_recorded p1
WHERE date_submitted > '" . $week_start . "'
AND date_submitted < '" . $week_end . "'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM picks_recorded p2
    WHERE p2.user_id = p1.user_id
    AND p2.date_submitted > p1.date_submitted
    AND p2.date_submitted < '" . $week_end . "'
)
```